# show and hide divs on click on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

1. List item

I am using the following code to hide a div and show the other.

page1

```
<a id="show" href="2#dk" onclick='document();'>mylink</a>
<a id="show1" href="2#dh" onclick='document();'>mylink</a>
```

page 2

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("dk").show();
        $("dh").hide();
    });
    $("#show1").click(function(){
        $("dh").show();
        $("dk").hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dk">mylink</a>
<div id="dh">mylink</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This works on one page but not after the anchor tag loads up another page.

**PREMISE**
I have pages:-

1. first
2. second

I want links on on page and divs on second page

1. frist page links
2. divs

**OBJECTIVE**

1. If the page is first page, links need to be on this page
2. If the page is second page, then I wish to hide the divs that are not link to the link thats clicked

you can see here what i mean even i will put account detials that ppl can look at code and try if they want
http://testscripten.enjin.com/login

- username:testscripten
- password:test12345

  go to admin and then edit
  page layout and next to text will a pencil to change html or java

Comment: Please show the other html document that you're talking about.

Comment: You have two div's. and you want to toggle between the divs?

Comment: got 2 link so if you click on it show the one thats linked to the link and hid the other one

Comment: Inside the <a> tag you wrote `href="dk"`. It is not even valid HTML. Put the two div's in two separate files and link them on the first page.

Comment: for got the 2#dk  the 2 is page 2 because its an enjin site cant use .html

Comment: @M.odc doesn't my solution work?

Comment: what is #show #show1 ?

Comment: Your class names of `toShowOnSecondPage` seem backwards from your description of desired action

Answer (score 0):

1. use AngularJS and SPA model to avoid page reload.
2. You can use also variables in url
3. If you need to reload page and have values on different pages you have to set cookie or webStorage http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp
4. Why don't you use php?

Comment: There's usually a simpler solution than changing the entire architecture of your app.

Comment: Usually it is easier to change technology on the start of the project than in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use window.location.href to get the link of the page you're currently on and then accordingly hide/show your buttons.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var pageName = window.location.href;
$(document).ready(function(){

    if(pageName === "dh"){
        $("#show").show();
        $("#show1").hide();
    } else if(pageName === "dk") {
        $("show1").show();
        $("show").hide();
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="show" href="dk">mylink</a> <!--No need for onclick if you're using jQuery-->
<a id="show1" href="dh">mylink</a> <!--No need for onclick if you're using jQuery-->
```

I am not sure of "dk" and "dh" being real links, if you have kept those as placeholders then this should work.

Comment: dh and dk are divs forgot to put 2# before it so it should be 2#dk or dh

Comment: so "dh" and "dk" are not the links ? if not what are you linking to?

Comment: the 2 is the link it means page 2 and dh and dk are divs

Answer (score 0):

Simply show/hide based upon the path name containing the strings you specify:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.toShowOnFirstPage').toggle(location.pathname.indexOf("first")!== -1);
    $('div.toShowOnSecondPage').toggle(location.pathname.indexOf("second")!== -1);
});
```